# Insert into a table from two different tables

Tags: mysql

Here I have 3 tables.

- sbs_users
- sbs_permissions
- sbs_user_permissions

let's say the data of each table are:

```
- sbs_users(table1)
userid    username
1         john
2         albert

- sbs_permissions(table2)
permissionid    permission
1               create
2               edit

- sbs_user_permissions(table3)
upid(autoid)    userid    permissionid
```

What I wanna do is insert into table3 with the all data from table2 but only get the last id in table1.

So expected after insert is:

```
- sbs_user_permissions(table3)
upid(autoid)    userid    permissionid
1               2         1
2               2         2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read you correctly, you want to give all permissions to the user with the max user id? If so, this:

```
insert into user_permissions select u.id, p.id from
  users u cross join permissions p
  where u.id = (select max(id) from users);
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dbfe/1)

Comment: Yes it helps me. i just need to specify columns to be inserted in INSERT INTO user_permissions(column1, column2, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this...

```
INSERT INTO sbs_user_permissions (userid, permissionid)

SELECT u.userid, p.permissionid
FROM sbs_users u
INNER JOIN sbs_permissions p ON 1=1
WHERE u.userid = 2;
```